# groupBy but for objects and each key

Tags: lodash

I have three objects:

```
 {a:1,b:2}, {a:11, b:22}, { a: 111 }
```

I want to get:

```
 {a: [1, 11, 111], b: [2, 22]}
```

We see this is like `groupBy` but I cannot find out how to do this with objects. I wrote this complicated thing that does it:

```
const mergeValuesByKey = (...objects) =>
  _.mapValues(
    _.groupBy(
      _.flatten(objects.map((obj) => Object.entries(obj))).map((pair) =>
        _.fromPairs([pair])
      ),
      (singleElementObject) => Object.keys(singleElementObject)[0]
    ),
    (singleValueObjects) =>
    singleValueObjects.map(
      (singleValueObject) => Object.values(singleValueObject)[0]
    )
  );
```

Is there anything simpler than this? Maybe a single method from lodash?

Comment: If you think about a simpler version, maybe a single function from lodash then you can refer to my answer that may help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want, is nothing but a simple merge (in [lodash](https://lodash.com/)) with a callback that handles the concatenation.

Let's have a snippet:

```js
const input = [{a:1,b:2}, {a:11, b:22}, {a: 111}];

const res = _.mergeWith({}, ...input, (s = [], o) => [...s, o]);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In case you don't want to built a array as a input (to have dynamically n number of inputs) you can simply pass them to the function one by one (as others given example), let's tweak the same code for that and replace the `...input` by passing all the inputs one by one manually as argument instead

```js
//Pass them here:           ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ // 
const res = _.mergeWith({}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:11, b:22}, {a:111}, (s = [], o) => [...s, o]);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've added a lodash/fp version of your answer.

Comment: @OriDrori I appreciate you for adding (and adapting) valuable content for the community, which really add values.

Comment: This is fantastic! I was hoping to learn lodash utils with this, and lodash came through! So simple thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `_.flatMap()` with pairs to get an array of [key, value]. Group the pairs by the `_.head()` (the key). Use `_.mapValues()` to map each group by `_.last()` (the value).

```js
const mergeValuesByKey = (...objects) => {
  const pairs = _.flatMap(objects, _.toPairs); // get an array of pairs
  const groups = _.groupBy(pairs, _.head); // group them by the key
  
  return _.mapValues(groups, g => g.map(_.last)); // map each group to an array of values
}


const result = mergeValuesByKey({a:1,b:2}, {a:11, b:22}, { a: 111 })

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

With lodash/fp you can generate a pointfree function using `_.rest()` & `_.flow()` that does the same thing:

```js
const { rest, flow, flatMap, toPairs, groupBy, head, mapValues, map, last } = _

const mergeValuesByKey = rest(flow(
  flatMap(toPairs),
  groupBy(head),
  mapValues(map(last)),
))


const result = mergeValuesByKey({a:1,b:2}, {a:11, b:22}, { a: 111 })

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

And a lodash/fp version of [@KoushikChatterjee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61954955/5157454). Use `_.rest()` to collect parameters to an array, and merge the items in the array using `_.mergeAllWith()`, and `_.concat()` as the merge customizer:

```js
const { rest, mergeAllWith, concat } = _

const mergeValuesByKey = rest(mergeAllWith(concat))


const result = mergeValuesByKey({a:1,b:2}, {a:11, b:22}, { a: 111 })

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: This is awesome example to learn even lodash fp! Thank you! I didn't know head could be used like this!

Comment: @OriDrori  flatmap, group, and mapvalues are not required for the lodash verson, it's a simple merge. for reference, see my answer.

Comment: There's more than one way to skin a cat :)

Comment: No, what all I wanted to say is, this is very simple, not at all that complex...

Comment: That's fine. Your solution is indeed shorter, and uses a single method like the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a javascript solution for same, We have group all object in an array using spread syntax and using `array#reduce` iterating through it. For each object, we iterate all its key and create a new table and add all values in an array.

```js
const mergeValueByKeys = (...objects) => objects.reduce((r, o) => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
    r[k] = r[k] || [];
    r[k].push(o[k]);
  });
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(mergeValueByKeys({ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 11, b: 22 }, {a: 111}));
```

Comment: This is so much cleaner than the lodash! I will accept this as solution due to that!

Comment: @Noitidart rather you can say this is much ahead in case of performance, we use lodash (some extra line of code written that can be consumed by us) to reduce our complex code volume and make it much cleaner and have better readability. I have added an answer with lodash to have much more readability and looks much cleaner